# 3 test groups, each group with different N of rats, Each rat with different n of D measurements...unsure which test to use to compare

Tags: anova, variance

Lets say I am trying to figure out a treatment that increases the thickness of a hair follicle. I have 3 groups: 7 Rats successfully treated with A, 3 Rats successfully treated with B and 5 healthy Rats as controls. I then measure hair follicles diameters (D) on each rat...the number of measurements may  differ with each rat (some I've measure 100 hairs, others 500+ are measured) and I now want to figure out if the treatment had significant impact on the hair follicle diameter....what test do I use and how is best to group the data for analysis?

...The reason I ask is because I feel if I just take the aggregate number of the hairs from group A and compare it (via anova or welch?) to the aggregate number of hairs from group B and the controls then I lose the variability BETWEEN measurements obtained from different rats of the same group? Don't I? Or is it that it doesn't matter? But then if I take the average for each Rat in a group and so then I have N measurements per group (either 3, 7 or 5 for A, B and control respectively) then I lose the variability in measurements WITHIN one Rat.

I'm sure the answer is obvious and I'm just a stats noob but clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to test the effect of a drug on one animal, then it's only fair to compare hairs from individual animals and not mix up hairs of multiple animals in a group. That said, you have three groups of rats but you should convert them into three groups of hairs by choosing one rat for every group. You should then perform an analysis of variance with post-hoc testing (Tukey's HSD test) in order to get all pairwise differences of the means between your groups. If your data is not normal then you should test with a nonparametric equivalent (Kruskal-Wallis with Bonferroni correction).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Digio.

But I still don't completely follow....If I group them into 3 group of hairs (hairs from rats treated with A, hairs from rats treated with B and hairs from control rats) then aren't still mixing up hairs from multiple animals from a group? And if not...then how can I just choose one rat randomly from each group to compare and ignore the others? I'm obviously missing something in your explanation....

Sorry for the ignorance and thank you in advance for the clarification.

Comment: I only described one out of many possible ways to conduct your experiment (which is what I would try first). First way: Suppose you have only sampled 1 rat for each medicine and 1 for control (500 hairs per rat). That leaves you with 3 hair groups: A, B, C(ontrol). You should perform analysis of variance (with post-hoc testing) in order to get the difference between the means of pairs A-B, A-C, B-C. Obviously, you want significant p-values for paris A-C and B-C, while ideally no difference in A-B. Taking 1 large sample per rat is the most statistically unbiased method.

Comment: If method 1 fails to detect a difference then you should try comparing all your rats from all your groups as 15 separate samples, where you will hope to observe that your 35 pairwise comparisons between A-C and/or your 15 pairwise comparisons between B-C will yield significant differences. This method will produce a LOT of comparisons and I would not recommend it unless you're aiming for a high impact factor or method 1 fails.

Comment: A 3rd method would be to mix up all hairs from all 7 rats in group A, all hairs from all 5 rats in group C, and all hairs from all 3 rats in group B, and then run ANOVA on those 3 groups. This would be for me the most biased method since you're merging multiple independent events into one. If you can, go for method 1 with large samples (the more hair the better). I believe that with any of those methods you can publish your results, but the better method will get you a higher impact factor.